# getting the width of threshold result (lines)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get the width or the thickness of two lines using opencv! I'm using the `threshold` function to get a higher representation of the line like:

[image: threshold result]

my question is how can get the thickness of  the lines in pixel, I try to use the `HoughLinesP` function but I'm not sure that the result is correct : 
[image: houlinesP result]

here is my code for what I tried :

```
.........................................
    vector<Mat> laserChannels;
    vector<Vec4i> lines;
        Mat laserCross;
Mat otsu;

    while (key!= 27){

        cap >> laserCross;
        split(laserCross, laserChannels);

threshold(laserChannels[2], otsu, 50, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

HoughLinesP( otsu, lines, 1, CV_PI/2, 1, 400,100  );

 for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        line( laserCross, Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
            Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 1, 8 );
     }

 std::cout << lines.size()<< std::endl;  
................................................
```

the lines size is 24 25  does that mean that the line are 12 pixel thick ? 
thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Wait....the output from the `vector<T>::size` function is giving you two values?

Comment: No just one but it is not constant !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you work with morphological filters, firstly. Your first picture is need some smoothing.

After that, you can get line boundries with `Image-erode(Image)`.

Next thing you can do is, fit Hough Lines to boundry image and get most powerfull n lines.

Voilà, you get most powerfull n lines, analytic parameters. (Rho & Theta)

Comment: does smoothing the image not influence the result that I get ?

Comment: no, i dont think so. But if you want to avoid smoothing, try morphological closing. After closing, you need to get edges of images. for more accuracy of hough transform, your edges must as thin as possible. I suggest you, first erode closed image with (3,3) kernel. And substract from closed image. That will give you one-pixel-width edge image. Then apply Hough Transform, then profit